# How to share fragments between multiple types in Graphql schema

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm using node.js as backend and want to define theses two types that share many fields in a graphql file:

```
type Customer {
    _id: ObjectID,
    first_name: String
    last_name: String,
    mobile: String,
    national_code: NonNegativeInt,
    
    # plus some different fields
}

type CustomerInformation{
    _id: ObjectID,
    first_name: String
    last_name: String,
    mobile: String,
    national_code: NonNegativeInt,
    
    # plus some different fields
}
```

So, we can define a fragment:

```
fragment CoreCustomerFragment on Customer {
    _id: ObjectID,
    first_name: String
    last_name: String,
    mobile: String,
    national_code: NonNegativeInt,
}
```

So what is the correct way of reusing the defined fragment in both **Customer** and **CustomerInformation** types? I tried the below code:

```
type Customer {
    ...CoreCustomerFragment,
    field1: String
}
type CustomerInformation{
    ...CoreCustomerFragment,
    field2: String
}
```

and I got errors like *Customer must define one or more fields*